# Frequency Sort Array Of Objects in JS and if frequency Matches sort on basis of object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have Array of objects

```
[
    {"X" : {
        "price" : "5"
      }
    },
    {"Y" : {
        "price" : "3"
      }
    },
    {"Y" : {
        "price" : "3"
      }
    },
    {"Z" : {
        "price" : "4"
      }
    },
    {"Q" : {
        "price" : "2"
      }
    },
    {"X" : {
        "price" : "5"
      }
    },
    {"Z" : {
        "price" : "4"
      }
    },
    {"X" : {
        "price" : "5"
      }
    }
]
```

I want to frequency Sort the array so that i get like `[object:count]`

How do i get the array to Transform arr to the format:

```
// [{key: x, count: 3, price: 5}},{key: y:, count: 2, price: 3}

[{x:3},{y:2},{z:2},{q:1}]
```

But the problem i am facing is if the frequency matches then the sort has to check the object's property i:e in this case the price and if the price is more than the other matching element that should be given weight age so in this case z price is more than y so z should be given priority.

```
[{x:3},{z:2},{y:2},{q:1}]
```

This is what i have tried so far:

```js
var a = ["x", "v"], b = ["x", "y"], c = ["d", "y"];
var d = a.concat(b, c);
    
function sortByFrequency(array) {
    var frequency = {};
    
    array.forEach(function(value) { frequency[value] = 0; });
  
    var uniques = array.filter(function(value) {
        return ++frequency[value] == 1;
    });
    
    return uniques.sort(function(a, b) {
        return frequency[b] - frequency[a];
    });
}
    
var frequency = sortByFrequency(d);
    
console.log(frequency);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Update after answer

I still donot know how to transform the array to this format

```js
   var arr = [
{"key":"X",
 "price" : "5",
 "count" :"3"
  }
,
{"key":"Y",
 "price" : "3",
 "count" :"2"
  }
,
{"key":"Z",
 "price" : "4",
 "count" : "2"
  }

];

var r = _.sortBy(_.sortBy(arr, 'price'), 'count'); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

now it works but how to get the object to this format from array

Comment: the output of your code is an array of strings, but the output in your text is an array of objects

Comment: yes i am not able to frequency sort objects i tried with arrays first

Comment: which one do you want? also, can you use external libraries (lodash)?

Comment: I want the objects and count not the string like [object : count ] and if count matches then sort by property . Preferably not using Loadash i can use only underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one using `reduce` and then `sort`.

**Explaination**

In order to achieve the desired result you can break down the task in below steps.

**1. Grouping** - Group by the items in the array using the Property names (x,y,z)
**2. Sorting**  - Sort the Result from Step1 in descending order where the first criteria is the count of items and the second criteria is the price.

**1.Grouping -** There isn't a native `group by` function in javascript. Therefore, we can make use of the `reduce` function which basically runs a function over the sequence of array and also returns the accumulated value.

a. In the reduce function, the accumulator will start with an empty array as mentioned in comments in code towards the end of the reduce function.

b. We get the property name like "x", "y", "z" by traversing the object. Also, we use the zeroth index as there is only one property like "x", "y", "z".

c. After that we check if the property is already in the Array or not.

d. If the Property is not in the array, then we need to add the property to the Array.

e. We create a object to handle the count and price information which would be used later.

f. If the Property already exists as mentioned in step c, then we need to increment the count of that property  `elementInArray[propName].count++;`

**2. Sorting**
    a. `sort` function takes a comparer function. In that function we compare the 2 items firsly by their `count`. If `count` is equal then we compare them by the `price`.

```js
var arr = [
    {"X" : {
        "price" : "5"
      }
    },
    {"Y" : {
        "price" : "3"
      }
    },
    {"Y" : {
        "price" : "3"
      }
    },
    {"Z" : {
        "price" : "4"
      }
    },
    {"Q" : {
        "price" : "2"
      }
    },
    {"X" : {
        "price" : "5"
      }
    },
    {"Z" : {
        "price" : "4"
      }
    },
    {"X" : {
        "price" : "5"
      }
    }
];

var frequency = arr.reduce(function (accumulatorObject, currentValue) { 
  var propName = Object.keys(currentValue)[0];
  var elementInArray = accumulatorObject.find((element) => Object.keys(element)[0] === propName);
  if (elementInArray) {
    elementInArray[propName].count++;
  }
  else {
    var newObject = {};
 newObject[propName]  = {};
 newObject[propName].count = 1;
 newObject[propName].price = +currentValue[propName].price;
 accumulatorObject.push(newObject);
 }
  return accumulatorObject;
}, []); //  // Accumulator starts with Empty array. 



frequency.sort(function(first,second){ 
    var diff =  second[Object.keys(second)].count - first[Object.keys(first)].count;
 if( diff === 0) {
  return second[Object.keys(second)].price - first[Object.keys(first)].price;
 }
return diff;});
console.log(frequency);
```

Comment: can you just explain me the accumulatorobject generation a bit

Comment: i wish i can upvote both urs and trincots answer both are correct but my votes are less then than 15 so its not reflecting, if you can please explain me a bit what you did

Comment: just a small doubt here while creating the object we are mapping each of the object keys into new object like 

newObject[propName]  = {};
 newObject[propName].count = 1;
 newObject[propName].price = +currentValue[propName].price;

But if suppose the objects keys are many like X has price,num,.... till 20 or 30 then do we need to map everything like this

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with the following ES6 code:

```js
function sortByFrequency(a) {
    return Array.from(
        a.reduce( (acc, o) => {
            const key = Object.keys(o)[0];
            const obj = acc.get(key) || Object.assign({ key, count: 0 }, o[key]);
            obj.count++;
            return acc.set(key, obj);
        }, new Map),
        ([key, obj]) => obj
    ).sort( (a, b) => b.count - a.count || b.price - a.price );
}

// Sample input
const a = [{
    X: {
        price: "5"
    }
}, {
    Y: {
        price: "3"
    }
}, {
    Y: {
        price: "3"
    }
}, {
    Z: {
        price: "4"
    }
}, {
    Q: {
        price: "2"
    }
}, {
    X: {
        price: "5"
    }
}, {
    Z: {
        price: "4"
    }
}, {
    X: {
        price: "5"
    }
}];

// Perform transformation & output
const res = sortByFrequency(a);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

The code builds a `Map` to ensure one entry per key. It is created with `reduce`, which gets as starting value `new Map` and which is then referenced as `acc`.

`reduce` will iterate over the input array `a`, and for each entry, it will extract the `key` with `Object.keys`. Since there is (and should be) only one key per object, it is extracted with `[0]` from the resulting array of keys.

Then with `acc.get` it is verified whether we already have an entry for that key. If so, `obj` is set to the object we had previously stored for that key. If not -- and this is the case in the first iteration -- a new object is created with `key` and `count` properties which get the correct values, and this object is merged with the deeper object in the input array (`o[key]`). Practically this means the `price` key and value are added to the object that already has `key` and `count`.

In either case (whether we created a new object or retrieved it from the Map), its count property is incremented.

Then this object is stored in the Map at the corresponding key with `acc.set(key, obj)`. This is returned to the `reduce` internals (i.e. the updated `acc` is returned), and this will be the value of `acc` in the next iteration, as that is how `reduce` works.

After the final iteration `reduce` will return the completed Map. This is then converted to an array with `Array.from`. During its execution we transform each entry, because by default a Map entry will be converted to a key/value pair (array), but we only want to keep the value (since it now contains the `key` property). So that is what happens in the callback argument provided to `Array.from`:

```
([key, obj]) => obj
```

Now we have an array of objects, where each object has the three desired properties. The only thing remaining is the sorting.

For that we subtract the counts of the two objects that are being compared (just as you already had done). However, when they are equal, we need to do more. In that case the difference is zero, which is falsy, and so with a boolean `||` we force JavaScript to evaluate what follows after it. In that case we sort by the price, again by subtracting the prices from each other. Note that your prices are strings, but the subtraction operator will convert them to numbers on the fly.

Comment: can you please explain it a bit its going over my head . Please

Comment: this will only generate the object array then i will use the sort by property right  it works thanks just can you help me wbout how you dit it

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer. Note that the sorting is done in the last line of the function. Let me know if you need more clarification on one or other aspect. Also, note that you can only accept one answer ;-)

Comment: yes i am sorry coudnt accept yours also coud'nt upvote

Comment: Sure you can accept mine, there is no restriction, but you made a choice to accept another (no problem if you feel the other answer is more worth of it, but you can change your decision). Upvoting is a different thing: you cannot yet upvote because you need a bit more reputation (you're almost there). Contrary to accepting, you can upvote several answers once you have the reputation.

Comment: yup i tried but the reputation is the problem, i accepted his ans as he kept the object structure as same just added another key  to it . that is the only reason.just fir curiosity will both be same in terms of performance ?

Comment: I looked at your desired output in your question (under the phrase *"I still donot know how to transform the array to this format "*), and produced exactly that output, so I don't know what you mean with "kept de object structure as same", since you were explicit in what you desired as output. So probably you intended something else than what I understood. For the performance, you could check yourself and run both of them on a large data set.

Comment: @trincot thanks once again now i have repo to upvote both u guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm just giving you the skeleton, but the `_.sortBy` method in lodash or underscore will perform a stable sort (i.e. preserve previous sorts) and let you apply multiple sorts.

```
function sortByFrequency(arr) {
    // Transform arr to the format: 
    // [{key: x, count: 3, price: 5}},{key: y:, count: 2, price: 3}, ... 

    arr = _.sortBy(_.sortBy(arr, 'price'), 'count'); 
    // in lodash, this is arr = _.sortBy(arr, ['price', 'count'])

    // transform arr into the format that you want 
    return arr.map(x => /* function */)

}
```

Comment: how do i transform the arr to this format and i only want to sort by price when count is similar otherwise i will not

Comment: which transformation do you need help with? 

yes, this function only sorts by price when count is the same. the outer sort "overwrites" the inner sort

Comment: Transform arr to the format: 
    // [{key: x, count: 3, price: 5}},{key: y:, count: 2, price: 3} you mentioned in the ans right

Comment: you already wrote the code to get `count` in your original question, except you store it in `frequency`. you can get price from the original array (maybe using `_.find`)

Comment: first we need to generate the frequency sorted array right that will help me get the sortBy how do i generate that array

Comment: i am not able to transform array of objects to this format  :( i mentioned it at last, you saw it is gives result as string not like object and count

Comment: Please help  i am not to transform  array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Just an Update to the Comment of John On Agalo Answer

Mapping each of the object keys into new object

In the Else block you can write this

```
 var newObject = {};  
    newObject[propName]  = {};
    newObject[propName].count = 1;
  Object.assign(newObject[propName], currentValue[propName]); // this line should do the trick also you need not convert proce to number as while sorting it is done at runtime .
    //newObject[propName].price = +currentValue[propName].price;
  accumulatorObject.push(newObject);
```

Comment: @Agalo hope this will work fine Please update new in JS